# How to cast type you dont have access to?

Tags: c#

I have a method, that takes a string as a parameter.
When I send a JToken, I get cast error.
Of course, I can use JToken.ToString(), but if I have a lot of JTokens, it becomes hard to handle all of them.
Is it possible to create implicit type casting from JToken to string (for example), considering I don't have access to the JToken or string class changing?

Comment: Can you provide code that you have tried?

Comment: Oh, if nothing changed in C#, the answer is "no": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526601/can-i-add-an-implicit-conversion-for-two-classes-which-i-dont-directly-control

Comment: @ManpritSinghSahota, I really don't think it matters. The key message is obvious: "is it possible, to create type conversion outside the class?"

Comment: If you really don't want to string everywhere, why not make it accept an object or make an overload that accepts an object and tostring in this method. I know it's terrible practice but it would work in your case.

Comment: @JoelHarkes, you are right. Just would know if there is a better way :)

Comment: @Bloodskys hehe There you hit an interesting statement 'better'. Some would say implicit conversion is never better because its a secret type cast ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To sum up what everybody has been saying: No this is not possible.

You can only implicit type cast when you own one of the classes: [Can I add an implicit conversion for two classes which I don't directly control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526601/can-i-add-an-implicit-conversion-for-two-classes-which-i-dont-directly-control)

The best way (in my opinion) To solve this problem is to use an extension method accepting JToken instead of string and tostring() it:

```
public static class MyExtensionMethodWrap 
{
     public static void AcceptJtoken(this ClassYouWantToExtend self, JToken token)
     {
         self.AcceptJtoken(token.ToString());
     }
}
```

This way you don't make an useless and confusing method on the `ClassYouWantToExtend`  but you do have the possibility for yourself to directly inject the JToken.

### Addition

You can make the extension method/class internal so this method is only available inside your single project. (not creating confusion anywhere else, by showing this method)