# C# - Is it possible to implicitly convert from a tuple to a Vector2?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm wondering if it's possible to create an implicit conversion extension to convert from a tuple of floats to a System.Numerics.Vector2 so that I can do something like this to create a Vector2:

```
Vector2 vector = (0.5f, 0.7f);
```

I've tried doing this

```
public static implicit operator Vector2(this (float x, float y) v) => new Vector2(v.x, v.y);
```

but it doesn't seem like the this keyword works with a tuple.

It isn't important for me that this works it would just be nice if it did.

Edit:

Found my answer: [Can I add an implicit conversion for two classes which I don't directly control?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5526601/8585017)
Don't know how I didn't find it the first time I was searching.

Comment: Not possible. A conversion operator must be defined on one of the two types. Both are from .Net, so you can't. Nearest option would be an extension method

Comment: Your question is just solved.